# PHP, replying to an email not working

Tags: php

I'm attempting to reply to an email with php.  I use php imap to fetch the email from the mail server and get the `message-id`.. i'm attempting to reply to the email but the email still shows up as a new message rather than a reply with threaded messages?

```
$inbox = imap_open($hostname,$username,$password) or die('Cannot connect to email: ' . imap_last_error());
$emails = imap_search($inbox,'ALL');

if($emails) {

rsort($emails);

foreach($emails as $email_number) {
$overview = imap_fetch_overview($inbox,$email_number,0);
$message_id = $overview[0]->message_id;
$references[] = $overview[0]->message_id;

}

$references = implode(" ",$references);

$headers = "From: <test@domain.co.uk> \r\n";
$headers .= "In-Reply-To: $message_id\r\n";
$headers .= "References: $references\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html;\r\n";
$subject = "testing";
$message = "test message2";
mail( "test2@domain.co.uk", $subject, $message, $headers );
```

I'm using the headers `In-Reply-To` and `References` from http://www.jwz.org/doc/threading.html.  The subject is also identical.  How do i solve?

Comment: its not clear bro :)

Answer (score 0):

I had looked into your code and noticed few things that might be the cause of the problem. Not sure whether its causing the problem or not.

1. `if($emails)`  will always be true whether its empty or not as its an array and it has been set successfully . Do `print_r($emails)` to check whether `imap_search()` returned and empty array or not.
2. In line `$message_id = $overview[0]->message_id;` the message id will always be the last `$overview[0]->message_id` , whether its inside a foreach, as its just a variable and would be assigned new each round of the loop and finally only the last would be preserved.
3. Not Sure, but i think in line `$references[] = $overview[0]->message_id;`i think it's a typo, it should actually be `$references[] = $overview[0]->references;` . One more thing about `$references[]` is that as it is now, at the end of foreach it will carry all the message id of all the emails.
4. Don't understand why but, I see you have fetched overview of all emails from inbox but only reply to a single mail has been considered and used finally.

Don't know for sure but trying to help :) Code would be something like this, have not been tested. But hope it works.

```
$inbox = imap_open($hostname,$username,$password) or die('Cannot connect to email: ' . imap_last_error());
$emails = imap_search($inbox,'ALL');

if(count($emails)>0) 
{

        rsort($emails);

        foreach($emails as $email_number) {
            $overview = imap_fetch_overview($inbox,$email_number,0);
            foreach($overview as $result){
                $message_id = $result->message_id;
                $references = $result->references;
            }
            //REMEMBER THIS WILL REPLY TO ALL YOUR INBOX EMAILS
            //NEED TO EDIT BEFORE USING
            reply($message_id,$references);
        }
}
function reply($message_id,$references){
        $headers = "From: <test@domain.co.uk> \r\n";
        $headers .= "In-Reply-To: ".$message_id."\r\n";
        $headers .= "References: ".$references."\r\n";
        $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html;\r\n";
        $subject = "testing";
        $message = "test message2";
        mail( "test2@domain.co.uk", $subject, $message, $headers );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

why not trying with smtp class ??     https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/class.phpmailer.php

Comment: This is what i've done, I've now implemented with phpmailer. I have it working with gmail but i cannot get it to work with webmail.  Any idea on what i'd have to do to solve this?  Do the headers have to be different for every mail application?